# JavaScript OOP: method definition with or without "prototype"

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, prototype

Is this code,

```
function Person() {
    function  myMethod() {
        alert ('hello');
    }
    this.method = myMethod;
}
```

equivalent to:

```
function Person() {    }
Person.prototype.method2  = function() {
    alert ('hello');
};
```

If yes, which method definition should I use and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

Comment: [Declaring javascript object method in constructor function vs. in prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772307/declaring-javascript-object-method-in-constructor-function-vs-in-prototype)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are functionally equivalent in your simple example, but behind the scenes work very differently. The `prototype` property on a function is really the "prototype template". It says "whenever an object is made and I am used as the object's constructor, give them this object as their prototype".

So all `Person`s created in your second example share the same copy of the `method2` method.

In the first example, each time the interpreter encounters the `function` keyword, then it creates a new function object. So in the first example, each instance of `Person` has their own copy of the `myMethod` method. The vast majority of the time this doesn't matter. But this first approach uses more memory, and sometimes that does matter.

They are not functionally equivalent in more interesting cases. In the first example, `myMethod` can access local variables defined in `Person`, but the second example cannot, as one difference.

Comment: Do you know of a case/context where the first method would be more useful ? Thank you.

Comment: The first situation allows you to have "private" variables. Any local variables defined in the `Person` method can be accessed by `myMethod`, but by nothing else. I recommend reading Crockford's *JavaScript the Good Parts*, as he goes into this pattern in great detail.

Answer (score 2):

In the first scenario, when you create a new person, `var person1 = new Person();`, it will have its own copy of `myMethod`. If you create 100 Person objects, they will each have their own copy of this method.

Using a prototype, every new Person object will share the method definition. This is much more memory efficient since there will only be one copy of the method.

If you are planning on having several Person objects, the second way is better.. but if there are only a few Person objects, it won't matter that much.

Comment: If the non-prototype method became popular, then perhaps the javascript runtimes would optimize away the difference...

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely equivalent.

In both cases, you define a function (constructor) `Person()` in the global namespace.

In the first case, you define a new function `myMethod()` in a closure inside the `Person()` function. Normally, the `myMethod()` function would not be available after the function/constructor `Person()` finishes. However, in this case you assign it to `this.method`. Thus, when you run the constructor

```
var myPerson = new Person();
```

A new object is created, then the `Person()` function is called with `this` set to the new object. Therefore, your new object receives a `method` field with `myMethod` function bound to it.

In the second case, `method2` is defined inside the `Person.prototype`. In this case, when you call

```
var myPerson = new Person();
```

there will be no field defined directly inside your new object (as you do nothing with `this` in the function `Person`). However, every object contains a reference to its prototype. If the object is created by calling `Person()`, this reference is set to `Person.prototype`. Thus, your object will ultimately contain `method2`, though not directly in itself, but in the prototype. So when you call

```
myPerson.method2();
```

the interpreter looks for `method2` inside the `myPerson` object and finds nothing, then it looks into the prototype of `myPerson`, which is `Person.prototype` and finds `method2`, so it calls it.

Long story short: in the first your constructor creates the method, so every time you call the constructor, a new method is created and inserted to the new object. In the second case, the method is stored in the prototype, so every object you create will have the reference to the same instance of your method.

Comment: Because of the lookup, performance wise would the first method be faster ?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMartin Yes. You get faster method lookup, but much more memory usage. The performance differences should be visible on repeated calls with long prototype chains. In this simple case, though, there is probably nothing to worry about.

Comment: I have a test case here to test for performance comparison of the approach: http://jsperf.com/method-definition-with-or-without-prototype

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equivalent. Although, they are similar. The first method will create a new function `myMethod` for each `new Person()` created.

The second method will have one function `method2` that is "shared" by all `Person's`.

Answer (score 0):

They have similar functionality but you should use the second approach (prototype) because when you will create an object using `new Person()` every object will share the same `method2` but using the first approach each new object will have it's own `myMethod()` that will consume moe memory.

**A few days ago I asked a similar question and got** [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156702/oop-javascript-and-simple-class-instantiation).